# Duplicate entries in join table. Using Hibernate, Spring

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have 3 Tables :

**Entity**

```
CREATE TABLE `entity` (
  `entity_number` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `surname` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `id_number` varchar(13) DEFAULT NULL,
  `gender` varchar(7) DEFAULT NULL,
  `age` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_of_birth` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `preferred_language` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ethnic_group` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `username` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`entity_number`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id_number_UNIQUE` (`id_number`)
)
```

**Contacts**

```
CREATE TABLE `contacts` (
  `contact_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `contact_type` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `value` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`contact_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `contact_id_UNIQUE` (`contact_id`)
)
```

**con_contact_entity**

```
CREATE TABLE `con_contact_entity` (
  `entity_number` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `contact_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`entity_number`,`contact_id`),
  KEY `FK_ENTITY_NUMBER` (`entity_number`),
  KEY `FK_CONTACT_ID` (`contact_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_CONTACT_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`contact_id`) REFERENCES `contacts` (`contact_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_ENTITY_NUMBER` FOREIGN KEY (`entity_number`) REFERENCES `entity` (`entity_number`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
)
```

Then i have my 3 pojos: (Only pasted relevant parts)

**Entity**

```
@javax.persistence.Entity
@Table (name = "ENTITY")
@Inheritance (strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Entity {

@ManyToMany (targetEntity = Contact.class, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable (name = "con_contact_entity", joinColumns = @JoinColumn (name = "entity_number"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn (name = "contact_id"))
    private Set<Contact> contactInfo;

...
}
```

**Contact**

```
@XmlAccessorType (XmlAccessType.NONE)
@XmlType (name = "Contact", propOrder = {"typeOfContact", "contactValue"})
@Entity @Table (name = "CONTACTS")
public class Contact {

@Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long contact_id;

    @XmlElement (name = "TypeOfContact", required = true, nillable = false)
    @Column (name = "contact_type") @Enumerated (EnumType.STRING)
    private ContactType typeOfContact;

    @XmlElement (name = "ContactValue", required = true, nillable = false)
    @Column (name = "value")
    private String contactValue;

...
}
```

If i add JOE as an entity with contact details (Type=HomeTel, Value=123456789), and then add JOE's wife who wants to add the same contact details, then there is a duplicate entry in Contact table. How can i make hibernate check for existing duplicate, and if found, just reference those contact details in the con_contact_entity table.

Example: result table data would be:

```
**ENTITY**
123   MR   JOE   ....
124   MRS  JANE  ....

**CON_CONTACT_ENTITY**
123   1
124   1

**CONTACTS**
1   HOMETEL   123456789
```

Comment: As per my knowledge there is no such feature in hibernate. you have to query for existing record(matching all contact values) from contacts and set the resultant Contact to your Entity object if found one, otherwise keep the user provided values intact to insert new record in Contacts table.

Comment: I thought it would just be an annotation or something. Maybe I should just query for duplicate in contacts table, and if found add a row to con_contact_entity with the reference to it. That's what I understand from your comment Pokuri? What should my cascade be set to when deleting an entity, since if I delete JOE, then his contact and the joined table entry will be removed too, thereby removing MRS JANE's HOMETEL too.